# Preventing a project from compiling with success under certain conditions

Tags: xcode, cocoa

Sometimes I have to turn certain features on for a project, like some flags or itunes file sharing that I do not want to be turned on when I archive the project to submit it to Apple.

Is there a way to force to prevent a project from compiling correctly and show an error on Xcode (I mean that red badge icon on Xcode's toolbar) if certain conditions are met?

Something like

```
if (some condition)
  do not compile or cause a compile error
```

I need xcode to tell me that I have forgotten something that is not supposed to ship on the final release.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a preprocessor directive `#error` that should work for you:

```c
#if !FLAG_THAT_SHOULD_BE_SET
#error You should set FLAG_THAT_SHOULD_BE_SET
#endif
```

From the C standard:

> The implementation shall not successfully translate a preprocessing translation unit containing a **`#error`** preprocessing directive unless it is part of a group skipped by conditional inclusion.

Comment: just an additional question: and if I want it to just show an error but continue compiling. I need both cases: do not compile and show a warning but compile. Thanks again.

Comment: @RubberDuck, there's a `#warning` directive, too.  `clang` (which I presume you're using since you tagged your question [xcode]) also supports `#pragma message`.